# Duplicated results by using EntityGraph in the case of OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitygraph

I decided to use Entity Graph capability of JPA 2.1 in my recently started project but I faced with a problem.

It goes well when you extend your graph over ManyToOne relationships but for OneToMany, results get duplicated because my provider (Hibernate) uses a left outer join.

I saw some solutions they came up with Distinct key word to tackle this problem but I think it is a tricky solution, even yet How we can get next level Entities Distinct.

I mean if I have 3 entities A, B and C
I will use Distinct on A not B where B has a OneToMany relationship to C then we get duplicated records of B inside A and so on

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

When we add Distinct to our Query, what is generated as SQL doesn't have any effect over the result provided from database because **as far as I know Distinct keyword acts on all columns lied in front of it**. Then the result (in this case) provided from database by Distinct or without would be the same.

But **Distinct says to JPA or its provider to get the most left table's records on the result collection distinct**. And this is the point which leads us to what we expect as the result.

Please if I misunderstood, correct me